# Recharts remove line from linechart

Tags: javascript

I need a way to remove the connecting lines and show only the dots on recharts linechart.
Here is a sample code. My reason is because I was originally using a scatter plot to display a large amount of data but it doesnt change much and it ends up looking like the linegraph. I was having some rendering issues being slow with scatter plot that is why I want to switch to a linegraph. Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-kec3v?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1218). I want all the dots to appear in the sample but the lines to be gone. I cant find a prop that does this maybe I missed it

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import {
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from "recharts";

const data = [
  {
    name: "Page A",
    uv: 4000,
    pv: 2400,
    amt: 2400
  },
  {
    name: "Page B",
    uv: 3000,
    pv: 1398,
    amt: 2210
  },
  {
    name: "Page C",
    uv: 2000,
    pv: 9800,
    amt: 2290
  },
  {
    name: "Page D",
    uv: 2780,
    pv: 3908,
    amt: 2000
  },
  {
    name: "Page E",
    uv: 1890,
    pv: 4800,
    amt: 2181
  },
  {
    name: "Page F",
    uv: 2390,
    pv: 3800,
    amt: 2500
  },
  {
    name: "Page G",
    uv: 3490,
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <LineChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <XAxis dataKey="name" />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Line
        type="monotone"
        dataKey="pv"
        stroke="#8884d8"
        activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
      />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
    </LineChart>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the line by setting the `stroke` option to `none`

Since this will remove both the line and the dots, we'll need to specify a color for the dots:

```js
<Line
    type="monotone"
    dataKey="pv"
    stroke="none"
    dot={{ stroke: "#ff0000" }}
    activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
/>
```

---

- Updated CodeSandbox can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-z8n73r).
- Visual output of the above sandbox:

  [image]